# PHP Remove string after a certain character to before character

Tags: php

```
$text= "This is a text1 i want to replace before # text2 i want to replace 
before # text3"

Start point ="text1"
End point = "#"
Replace= "@@@@@@"
```

Note "i want to replace before" is changeable sentence
Result will be "This is a @@@@@@ text2 i want to remove before # text3"

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want

```
$mystring = "This is a text1 i want to replace before # text2 i want to replace before # text3";

$start = "text1";
$end = "#";
$replace= "@@@@@@";

$pos1 = strpos($mystring, $start);
$pos2 = strpos($mystring, $end, $pos1);

$length=$pos2+ strlen($end) - $pos1;

$result = substr_replace($mystring,$replace,$pos1,$length);
echo $result;
```

What I have done here is find the string positions. $pos1 & $pos2 are the the positions of your start and ending string.

Then calculated the length between those two strings where strlen($end) is the length of your ending string (so that we can grab the end string also).

Finally just used the regular substr_replace function.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Welcome. Since it solved your problem can you please accept the answer. @user1130537